# What does unlocking the bootloader have to do with rooting?

Tags: rooting, bootloader

Every procedure I found to root my phone required to *unlock the bootloader* as a prerequisite. Well, I have an idea of what a bootloader is and it seems that there is something that prevents it from being changed, which is implied in the answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46833/what-does-unlocking-the-bootloader-do). Also, the answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166260/is-it-required-to-unlock-the-bootloader-to-root-normally) says that it is not necessary.

The question remains: **Why are rooting instructions asking to unlock the bootloader?**

Aren't these separate things? Or do some rooting procedures also change the boot loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unlocking boot loader is NOT mandatory for all devices. Unlocking, is to facilitate flashing of unsigned images as in custom ROMs. Even if you unlock bootloader, for rooting only, it exposes you to security concerns (see question linked at end of this answer ).
- If your bootloader is unlocked already, there is no need to unlock . There are devices with unlocked bootloader and for those you can proceed to root directly. For [example](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/178054/131553)
  Majority of devices seem to require unlocking
- This question explains well things about unlocking
  [Is it possible to unlock the bootloader without root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/64030/131553)
- Rooting procedures do NOT change the bootloader. That would be dangerous

Also see , [Why does unlocking the bootloader wipe phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33691/131553)

Comment: Had seen that question but since it looked like rooting requires boot unlocking, it seemed reasonable to assume that one can unlock without root, otherwise it would be a circular dependency. What I am reading between the lines in your first point is that the bootloader *must* be unlocked but you only need to unlock it if it is locked to start with. Right?

Comment: Great. Thanks! One more detail to answer my question in bold: If it is only to flash a custom ROM, why do rooting instructions ask for unlocking? Is it not possible to root with the bootloader is locked?

Comment: *Is it not possible to root with the bootloader is locked?* No. Not possible. If the bootloader is unlocked -unless, the is an exploit discovered that bypass this requirement

Comment: Unlocking bootloader is related to security. See the last point in my answer